I'd like to know how I could use Dynamic Filtering (with MappingJacksonValue) and implement HATEOS (EntityModel) for my particular REST API?
So I have been learning REST API with Spring Boot
I have a User bean:
@JsonFilter("UserFilter")
public class User {

    private int id;

    @Size(min = 2, message = "Name should have at least 2 characters")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("Birth Date")
    @Past(message = "Birth date should be in the past")
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    public User(int id, String name, LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", birth=" + birthDate +
                '}';
    }
}

and I have a UserDao to access User data:
@Component
public class UserDaoService {

    private static List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        users.add(new User(1, "Alice", LocalDate.now()
                .minusYears(18)
                .minusMonths(1)));
        users.add(new User(2, "Bob", LocalDate.now()
                .minusYears(21)
                .plusMonths(3)
                .plusDays(5)));
        users.add(new User(3, "Cathy", LocalDate.now()
                .minusDays(7)
                .minusYears(25)));
        users.add(new User(4, "David", LocalDate.now()
                .minusYears(23)));
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
        return users;
    }

    public User findById(int id) {
        return users.stream()
                .filter(user -> user.getId() == id)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
}

I also have a UserController where I map Endpoints/Requests to REST API responses:
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private UserDaoService service;

    public UserController(UserDaoService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public MappingJacksonValue findAllUsers() {
        List<User> usersList = service.findAll();
        MappingJacksonValue mjv = new MappingJacksonValue(usersList);
        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("name", "Birth Date");
        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("UserFilter", filter);
        mjv.setFilters(filters);
        return mjv;
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public EntityModel<User> findUserById(@PathVariable int id) {
        User usr = service.findById(id);
        if (usr == null)
            throw new UserNotFoundException("id:" + id);

        EntityModel<User> model = EntityModel.of(usr);
        WebMvcLinkBuilder link = WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn(this.getClass()).findAllUsers());
        model.add(link.withRel("all-users"));
        return model;
    }
}

For the findAllUsers() method I tried to make use of dynamic filtering using MappingJacksonValue. For findUserById() method I don't want to apply any filtering but I do want to add a link to the full list of users (using EntityModel) when a person views details on a single user.
When I make a GET request to localhost:8080/users/3 I get the following error:
HttpMessageConversionException: type definition error: [simple type, class SpringBootFramwork.RESTAPI.beans.User]
caused by InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot resolve PropertyFilter with id 'UserFilter'; no FilterProvider configured (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel["content"])
It seems when I comment out the @JsonFilter annotation from the User bean the GET request works, but of course then there's no filtering when I GET localhost:8080/users (retrieve all of the users). Why is it when I add the @JsonFilter annotation to my User bean I get the above error? How can I fix this?
Expected Output:
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Cathy",
    "Birth Date": "1999-04-19",
    "_links": {
        "all-users": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/users"
        }
    }
}

